# How can I apply a check mark to a single Button() menu item in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to implement a single menu item that achieves three things when it is selected:

- Toggle a Boolean value true/false.
- Perform an action based on the new value.
- Show a checkmark next to the menu item when the new value is true.

I can't figure out how to add the checkmark. I tried using a Toggle() instead of a Button() but I could not get it to behave correctly. I couldn't get it to perform the action at the time the menu item is selected.

The following code behaves the way I want to but does not show a checkmark.

```
struct MenuView: View {
    @Binding var checkMarkOn: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Menu("Toggle Buttons") {
            Button("Showing Checkmark") {
                checkMarkOn = !checkMarkOn
                performAction(with: checkMarkOn)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps try: `Toggle(isOn: _checkMarkOn) { ... }.toggleStyle(.checkbox).disabled(true)` (grayed out) or `Toggle(isOn: .constant(checkMarkOn)) { ... }.toggleStyle(.checkbox)`

Comment: Try ```.toggle()```

Comment: No matter what I try I can't get Toggle() to call a function at the moment the menu item is selected. If someone could tell me how to do that it would solve my problem.